# minSdkVersion correctly defined in manifest still getting errors

Tags: android

In my `Android Manifest` I have these value set:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

But I keep getting errors like this:

```
Error:(7, 5) uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 10 declared in library …app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.facebook.android\facebook\3.21.1\AndroidManifest.xml
```

Or at another place where I using this code:

```
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

I get warning with red line that however when i run it runs fine:

```
`Call requires min API level 11 (current min is 9…`
```

Why is that when I have set minSdkVersion to way above than required?

Comment: Are you using gradle and AndroidStudio? Chances are the minSdk is set in the .gradle file for your app and its replacing the value in the manifest.

Comment: yes, that was the issue as @ianhanniballake pointed out below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Gradle, the `minSdkVersion` declared in your `build.gradle` file takes precedence over what is declared in your `AndroidManifest.xml` - in fact, you can remove those lines from your manifest entirely.

Comment: Solved. That was the issue, the one defined in `build.gradle` was `9`. Thankyou! Any way I can avoid this duplication. Can I access `@integer` resources inside a gradle file?

Comment: Just remove the lines from your `AndroidManifest.xml` - they will be auto-inserted by Gradle.

Answer (score -1):

The `minSdk` errors that you are getting is because of the libraries included and not because of your app. For example facebook requires minSdk 9 which is declared in its manifest

Comment: You've got it exactly backwards: the error message says Facebook requires version 10, but his build has a minSdkVersion of 9.